# Changing the address of a pointer to edit its value

Tags: c++, pointers

recently we were trying to use pointer to void, by passing a copy of its address to an instance of a class, in order for the instance to allocate it to the same memory space as an OpenCV Mat it contains, and that is contained in a stack of memory shared by the GPU and CPU to compute it with OpenCV+CUDA.

However while doing that we ran into an issue we didn't quite understand. When passing the address of the pointer to the object, we tried to edit that address so that the pointer was hosted on another space. And while that worked once that copy ran out of scope the value of that pointer returned to being what it was (I'll add a code snip since its confusing to even explain it). However if we accessed the content of the pointer's address that we passed to the function, and edit that, the original pointer is edited.

My hypothesis is that when we passed the pointer's address to the function a copy of the value of that memory address is made, and if that pointer to pointer is edited, the content of it is left undisturbed, while on the other function we accessed the content and directly edited it, hence the copy is left undisturbed and runs out of scope, while the content is edited correctly.

Here is a snip of the code where I try both things:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


void change_value(int **p, int *addr)
{
   *p = addr;   
}

void change_direction(int **p, int *addr)
{
   std::cout << "p value: " << p << std::endl;
   std::cout << "p contains: " << *p << std::endl;
   std::cout << "p contains contains: " << **p << std::endl;
   p = &addr;
   std::cout << "p value: " << p << std::endl;
   std::cout << "p contains: " << *p << std::endl;
   std::cout << "p contains contains: " << **p << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
   int *ptr = &a;
    
   std::cout << "ptr direction: " << &ptr << std::endl;
   std::cout << "ptr value: " << ptr << std::endl;
   std::cout << "ptr contains: " << *ptr << std::endl;
   std::cout << std::endl;

   change_value(&ptr, &b);
   std::cout << "change_value" << std::endl;
   std::cout << "ptr direction: " << &ptr << std::endl;
   std::cout << "ptr value: " << ptr << std::endl;
   std::cout << "ptr contains: " << *ptr << std::endl;
   std::cout << std::endl;

   change_direction(&ptr, &c);
   std::cout << std::endl;
   std::cout << "change_direction" << std::endl;
   std::cout << "ptr direction: " << &ptr << std::endl;
   std::cout << "ptr value: " << ptr << std::endl;
   std::cout << "ptr contains: " << *ptr << std::endl;

}
```

This is the output we got. We can see that while ptr is edited on change_value function, since we access to the content of p and edit it, it is not changed on change_direction, since the moment we edit p's address it stops pointing to ptr.

```
ptr direction: 0x710a27e3fe18
ptr value: 0x710a27e3fe0c
ptr contains: 1

change_value
ptr direction: 0x710a27e3fe18
ptr value: 0x710a27e3fe10
ptr contains: 2

p value: 0x710a27e3fe18
p contains: 0x710a27e3fe10
p contains contains: 2
p value: 0x710a27e3fdd8
p contains: 0x710a27e3fe14
p contains contains: 3

change_direction
ptr direction: 0x710a27e3fe18
ptr value: 0x710a27e3fe10
ptr contains: 2
```

If anyone could offer a better explanation of what happened I'd be most grateful.

Cheers.

Comment: `p = &addr;` should be `*p = addr;`, no? Although I'm a bit confused by your use of "direction", but otherwise the function will not be modifying what is passed to it as arguments

Comment: What exactly is your question/ confusion about ?

Comment: @AdrianMole Mole Yes you are totally right, I'll edit it right away, yes I meant address.

Comment: Could you try to clear up some other terms, too, please? Change a pointer: Do you mean cast the pointer type? What is instance? Instance of an object? CUDA kernel? Allocate to the same memory space: Do you mean placement new? Or the same general memory area? Or setting the pointer to a certain address? Your examples seem much simpler than the terms you used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*@463035818_is_not_a_number* offered a good answer that works well.
But there might be value in fully understanding what your original code is doing.

Beggining from the start:

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
int *ptr = &a;
```

This initializes three pieces of memory in stack memory containing the `int` values you gave (`a,b,c`) and one more piece of memory for your `ptr` variable that holds the address of `a`.

You then print out the address and the values of `ptr`, which obviously doesn't change any of the values.

---

Next is the call to `change_value(int **p, int *addr)` which executes.

```
*p = addr;
```

The parameter `p` in this case holds an address to an address to an `int` somewhere in memory, so `*p` is the address pointed to by p.
Setting that to `addr` changes the address `p` points to.

So in your specific code:

```
change_value(&ptr,&b);
```

Sets the value of `ptr` to be the address of `b`.

---

Then next is the `change_direction(int **p, int* addr)` call (which probably should be named `change_address`), which executes (ignoring the printing):

```
p = &addr;
```

This sets the parameter `p` to be the address of `addr`.

But since in C/C++ all functions are called by value *(in C there arent even any references, in C++ you have to specify it as @463035818_is_not_a_number mentioned)*, this doesnt do anything to the original values, that the function has been called with.

So the call:

```
change_direction(&ptr,&c)
```

Does not actually change what is held in `ptr`. At the beginning of the call to the function, the address of `ptr` (so `&ptr`) gets copied into a piece of stack-memory, which is then used in the function and freed after the function exits.

I hope this clears things up, pointers can be hard to wrap your head around sometimes.

Cheers.

Comment: Many thanks to all, your answers explain it amazingly! While I had the suspicion that p in change_direction (which should definitely be called change_address as you mention) was copying the address of the pointer to int I couldn't quite explain what was happening there. @JacobSachs thanks for the thorough analysis!

Comment: btw it is completely fine to have complementary answers. You *can*  but you don't *have to* refer to an existing answer. Tbh the reason I mention it is that you seem to refer to the other answer merely to state that you are going to present a more detailed one ... ;)

Comment: Yeah sorry i didnt word that beginning paragraph in a  good manner.

Comment: perhaps just remove it. It doesnt add necessary context but on the other hand it can get invalided in case I would decide to delete my answer. Don't get me wrong, it is difficult to critize when it is about my own answer. I would have made same suggestion if it wasnt my answer. No worries all fine, I think I understood the intention, and it is just a suggestion to make a good answer even better

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I understand the question, but if this:

```
void change_direction(int **p, int *addr)
{
   // ...
   p = &addr;
   // ...
}
```

Is supposed to modify the parameter passed to the function, then it isnt correct.

Parameters are passed by value unless you pass them by reference. Passing references is recommended, but if you like you can use pointers. However, then you need to modify what the pointer points to, not the pointer. In the function above `p` is local to the function. Modifying the value of `p` has no effect outside the function.

You probably want:

```
void change_direction(int **p, int *addr)
{
   // ...
   *p = addr;
   // ...
}
```

Or rather

```
void change_direction(int *&p, int *addr)
{
   // ...
   p = addr;   // p is a reference, hence no dereference needed
   // ...
}
```

Actually you should prefer `int*&` here, because a `nullptr` is not a valid paramter (and thats about the only reason you would use a pointer rather than a reference).

Comment: Awesome, I didn't realize I could just pass by reference the pointer to my function. That works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: @Leandro actually pointers arent that special with respect to that. The rule of thumb is rather simple: You want to modify it? Pass a reference. You don't want to modify? Pass by value or `const` reference. Same for pointers

Comment: BTW "p" in the first example is a pointer to a pointer to an int. So perhaps it should be called "pp" or "int **pp", whereas the "addr" is a pointer to an int, so being a pointer is implicit in the term address, otherwise it could be called "pint" or "pdata".

Comment: @Sebastian what you suggest is leaning towards [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation). It is mostly opinion based whether it is good style or not. I am completely against it. Imho names should not reflect the type of a variable, thats what their type is for. Consider you refactor to change the type of `p` then you would need to change its name too, just because its of different type, imho that is silly